# How to delete all references to database in xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb

Unable to drop a database. Mysql error log shows "InnoDB: Warning: MySQL is trying to drop database "DB_NAME"."",  InnoDB: though there are still open handles to table "DB_NAME"."XXX". Then the mysql server stops working.

Please Help!

Comment: Check the output from `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`  to identify what has an open connection. You can then `KILL <number>;` to terminate it.

Comment: but the server no longer working doesn't quite add up.

Comment: Just got it solved. there was a corrupt table in one of the databases. Had to delete ibdata file and other log files.